# Add non-click function inside of a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following problem. I have a `.one("click")` function with a variable that raises itself, and I need to add a function, that triggers, when the variable hits the wanted point. I mean, in the following code I need to use the connect function for the last 'last' img with the 'home' img, after the Result variable turns 9, which will produce a line between them, and I'll have a complete circle. Please read the code and try clicking on all img-es so that you can understand, what i need to achieve. Thanks in advance. 
Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Result = 0;

    $('img').one("click", function(){
        if( $('img.home').length == 0 ){
                        $(this).addClass('home');
        }

        if(Result <= 9){
            var $elem2 = $('span.last');
            var $elem1 = $(this).parent();
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');

            if ($elem2.length > 0) {    
                connect($elem1[0], $elem2[0], "#0F0", 5);
            } 
            else { 
                $elem1.addClass('last');
            }

            $('span').removeClass('last');
            $elem1.addClass('last');
            Result++;
        }
    });

});


function connect(div1, div2, color, thickness) {
    var off1 = getOffset(div1);
    var off2 = getOffset(div2);
            // bottom right
    var x1 = off1.left + off1.width;
    var y1 = off1.top + off1.height;
            // top right
    var x2 = off2.left + off2.width;
    var y2 = off2.top;
            // distance
    var length = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1) * (x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1) * (y2-y1)));
        distanz += parseInt(length);
            // center
    var cx = ((x1 + x2) / 2) - (length / 2);
    var cy = ((y1 + y2) / 2) - (thickness / 2);
            // angle
    var angle = Math.atan2((y1-y2),(x1-x2))*(180/Math.PI);
            // make hr
    var htmlLine = "<div style='padding:0px; margin:0px; height:" + thickness + "px; background-color:" + color + "; line-height:1px; position:absolute; left:" + cx + "px; top:" + cy + "px; width:" + length + "px; -moz-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -o-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -ms-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg);' />";
htmlLine = $(htmlLine);

    $('body').append(htmlLine);
    return htmlLine;
}


function getOffset( el ) {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var w = el.offsetWidth|0;
    var h = el.offsetHeight|0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
            x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
            y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
            el = el.offsetParent;
        }
    return { top: y, left: x, width: w, height: h };
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CDQhX/4/

I want to execute the connect(home and span images) after the last line is done and the Result is 9. This can't be done inside the click function, since I'm not clicking anywhere to trigger it. My knowledge don't let me work the problem around. So I appreciate any help. I'll be really glad to receive answers.

Comment: what you mean is difficult to understand

Comment: surely the result can only get to 9 when the image is clicked so it won't fire before that so why not fire it on the 9th click?

Comment: as @Pete suggested, connect the spans when result is 9

Comment: yeah, forget the if statemend, I was too lazy to delete it :D. When I fire it on the 9th click the last image is ignored and no line is created. Can you please edit the code, because when I do it, it just doesn't happen. Thanks

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/CDQhX/5/

Comment: Yeah. It's the same way I try it, but I need to go through all images, and if I apply it on this position I'll have ignored the last one. I can't figure out how to apply the function after a line is created between the 9th and 10th image, so that I can connect the 10th and the first.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CDQhX/7/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for this http://s7.directupload.net/images/140304/pqd5zpj5.png , not for this http://s14.directupload.net/images/140304/8umtnp46.png

Comment: yeah - did you try 6 or 7, I edited the link above because I realized I had linked the wrong last item, the above link should now work properly

Comment: THANKS MAN!!! You're saint u know :D. Really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what do you mean you are not clicking anywhere and you want it executed when the last img is clicked. Can't you just check if the img is last when it is clicked, and execute what you need?

Also, on the other hand, you can try `setTimeout` and `setInterval` as described here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html

So, for example, you could do something like this:

```
setInterval( function() {
  //do your thing
}, 500);
```

Which will execute the function every 500 milliseconds, so you could use that for periodic checking of your variables.

Comment: What i'm looking for is far easier, just I can't figure it out. You can see the images in the last comment to understand it better. Thanks anyway :)